# Mega-modular exponentiation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How can I find the answer of this type of modular exponentiation?
Here, one thing should be noticed, that is 'MOD' value may or may not be prime.
I need a generalized formula/method. Similar type question was asked before but there was solution under various condition. I didn't find my answer.

$$ (a^{b^{c^{{d^\ddots}^z}}})\bmod M\ =\ ?\ [\ 1\leq (a,b,c,....z,M) \leq  10^{16}\ 
 ]$$

Comment: What has been tried ?

Comment: Just do Euler's Theorem combined with Chinese Remainder theorem as many times as you need.  You seldom need to go very far.

Comment: I really don't know what "(a^b^c^d^...^z)%MOD = ? 1<= (a,b,c,....z,MOD)<= 10^16" is supposed to be asking. If "<=" means less than or equal I don't know what you are assuming about an order on modular equivalence (which don't have intrinsic order).

Comment: @fleablood sir, Would you please elaborate ?

Comment: You first.  What *ARE* you asking????  But to solve $a^{b^{c^d}} \pmod n$.  Solve $(\gcd(a,n))^{b^{c^d}} \equiv 0 \pmod \gcd(a,n)$. Let $a'=\frac a{\gcd(a,n)}$ and $n'=\frac n{\gcd(a,n)}$ and solve $a'^{(b\% \phi(n'))^{c^d}}\pmod n'$.  Etc.

Comment: is it supposed to be a parenthesized power tower ? It won't affect the method, but may affect the answer out of it.